# Typescript : Call instance method

Tags: angular, methods, typescript, interface

I have an interface:

```
export interface ISearchService {
    search(terms: string):  Observable<any>;
}
```

I have two services implementing this interface:

SearchMaleEmployeeService:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchMaleEmployeeService implements ISearchService {

  constructor() { }

  public search(terms: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('call: SearchMaleEmployeeService.search ' + terms);
  }
}
```

SearchFemaleEmployeeService:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchFemaleEmployeeService implements ISearchService {

  constructor() { }

  public search(terms: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('call: SearchFemaleEmployeeService.search ' + terms);
  }
}
```

In my search.component, I would like to call the search method of the service.

My search.component:

```
export class SearchComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('ISearchService') private searchService: ISearchService) { }

  onSearch(terms: string) {    
    this.searchService.search(terms);
  }
}
```

And finally, in the component which hosts SearchComponent:

```
providers: [
    { provide: 'ISearchService', useValue: SearchFemaleEmployeeService}
],
```

When I run the onSearch method in SearchComponent, I got this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./SearchComponent class SearchComponent - inline template:0:127 caused by: this.searchService.search is not a function
```

I think this is because I'm trying to call a method from a interface, but when I `console.log` `this.searchService`, it returns `SearchFemaleEmployeeService`, that mean that this is the good instance. Why do I have this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `useValue`

```
{provide: 'ISearchService', useValue: SearchFemaleEmployeeService}
```

which just uses the *value you provide*, which is a class, which in JS is a function. You should instead use `useClass`, then Angular will create it for you.

```
{provide: 'ISearchService', useClass: SearchFemaleEmployeeService}
```